# What are the UI colors for the YouTube superchat tiers?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I'm currently doing some work with the Youtube Live Streaming Api - more specifically the live chat messages API. Its all working fine for now but my main problem is with superchats and superstickers.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages#snippet.superChatDetails.tier

I'm reffering to this bit in youtube's livechat messages documentation. It addresses that each superchat has a tier variable, and that tier correspond's to a UI color which I will need when designing my UI. The documentation says

> The tier is based on the amount of money spent to purchase the message. It also determines the color used to highlight the message in the live chat UI, the maximum message length, and the amount of time that the message is pinned the ticker.

> The Super Chat tiers, which also cover Super Stickers, are documented in the YouTube Help Center. (See the expandable section about Super Chat purchase details.) In that list, the tier with the lowest purchase amount is tier 1, the next lowest amount is tier 2, and so forth. The Super Chat tiers, which also cover Super Stickers, are documented in the YouTube Help Center. (See the expandable section about Super Chat purchase details.) In that list, the tier with the lowest purchase amount is tier 1, the next lowest amount is tier 2, and so forth.

So I went ahead to the the Youtube Help Center and the closest thing I can find to it supposedly describing the youtube superchat tiers is this article below:

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9178268?visit_id=637544258197433496-560511224&rd=1

But again, this article really doesn't document anything that would be relevant to a developer.

So here is my question exactly. Does anybody out there know where I can find the documentation or if somebody knows what the YouTube Superchat tier levels and UI colors are?

If I were stuck on something like this, I would usually just test it out myself rather than trying to find specific documentation, but that's not really possible here. Since if I were to test every single tier, it would probably cost me hundreds of dollars in test donations.

**Extra question**:

Can anyone also explain what's going on with the whole authorDetails.sponsor vs the member resource, apparently its deprecated but I'm not sure about the exact situation of that?

I'm also trying to access the authorDetails.sponsor variable but apparently the whole Sponsor resource got deprecated and was changed to the Member resource. But then when I visit the member resource it says you need prior approval to use the members.list method but does that also include the authorDetails.sponsor variable?

Here are the documentation links below:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/members
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages#authorDetails.isChatSponsor
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/sponsors

Comment: Did you ever find any information about this? I am in the same situation and Google documentation is really annoying me now. Out of date or just missing info, very confusing (obviously the API has changed a bit since this question but the tiers are still undocumented) I think there are 5?

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed that Google does not provide documentation on this (even though the Super Chat API docs mention it is documented.)

I've found this chart to be a useful starting point: https://www.midiaresearch.com/storage/uploads/blog/images/2017/02/Screen-Shot-2017-02-09-at-09.50.17.png

In case that image is not available in the future, here are the values:

| Amount Range | Color | Time Displayed (in Ticker) | Max Characters |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $1.00 - $1.99 | Blue | 0s | 0 |
| $2.00 - $4.99 | Light blue | 0s | 50 |
| $5.00 - $9.99 | Green | 2m | 150 |
| $10.00 - $19.99 | Yellow | 5m | 200 |
| $20.00 - $49.99 | Orange | 10m | 225 |
| $50.00 - $99.99 | Magenta | 30m | 250 |
| $100.00 - $199.99 | Red | 1hr | 270 |
| $200.00 - $299.99 | Red | 2hr | 290 |
| $300.00 - $399.99 | Red | 3hr | 310 |
| $400.00 - $499.99 | Red | 4hr | 330 |
| $500.00+ | Red | 5hr | 350 |

The [Super Chat API docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages#properties) mention:

> In that list, the tier with the lowest purchase amount is tier 1, the next lowest amount is tier 2, and so forth.

It's probably safe to assume that there are 11 tiers for Super Chats.

---

edit: I wrote some code to calculate the colors for each amount. I verified that these colors are correct. Feel free to re-use it:

```js
/**
 * Calculate the colors for a given super chat amount.
 * Returns the background color [0], the header color (darkened) [1],
 * and the text color [2].
 * @param {string|number} amount
 * @returns {[string, string, string]}
 */
const getSuperChatColors = (amount) => {
  if (typeof amount === 'string') {
    amount = parseFloat(amount.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, ''))
  }

  if (amount >= 1 && amount <= 1.99) {
    return ['#1565C0', '#1565C0', '#FFFFFF']
  } else if (amount >= 2 && amount <= 4.99) {
    return ['#00E5FF', '#00B8D4', '#000000']
  } else if (amount >= 5 && amount <= 9.99) {
    return ['#0F9D58', '#0A8043', '#000000']
  } else if (amount >= 10 && amount <= 19.99) {
    return ['#FFCA28', '#FFB300', '#000000']
  } else if (amount >= 20 && amount <= 49.99) {
    return ['#F57C00', '#E65100', '#FFFFFF']
  } else if (amount >= 50 && amount <= 99.99) {
    return ['#E91E63', '#C2185B', '#FFFFFF']
  } else if (amount >= 100 && amount <= 199.99) {
    return ['#E62117', '#D00000', '#FFFFFF']
  } else if (amount >= 200 && amount <= 299.99) {
    return ['#E62117', '#D00000', '#FFFFFF']
  } else if (amount >= 300 && amount <= 399.99) {
    return ['#E62117', '#D00000', '#FFFFFF']
  } else if (amount >= 400 && amount <= 499.99) {
    return ['#E62117', '#D00000', '#FFFFFF']
  } else if (amount >= 500) {
    return ['#E62117', '#D00000', '#FFFFFF']
  } else {
    console.error('Invalid amount for super chat', amount)
    return ['#1565C0', '#1565C0', '#FFFFFF']
  }
}
```

Usage:

```js
const [bgColor, headerColor, textColor] = getSuperChatColors('$100.00')
// or
const [bgColor, headerColor, textColor] = getSuperChatColors(60)
// or
const [bgColor, headerColor, textColor] = getSuperChatColors('$1')
// or
const [bgColor, headerColor, textColor] = getSuperChatColors('20')
```